# accessing profile.newproperty in MVC web applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-profiles

I recently asked this question [How to persist anon user selection (ex: theme selection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706349/how-to-persist-anon-user-selection-ex-theme-selection). and started to learn about ASP.NET profiles and their properties in the web config. I tried the answer from the link but i was unable to access profile.newproperty

[How to assign Profile values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426609/how-to-assign-profile-values)
This question specifies that web-applications don't support profile out of the box and a custom model based on ProfileBase must be created. The question was answered in 2009 and I wanted to know if this is still the same case.

In a ASP.NET 4.0 web application can I access profile.newproperty with a property i defined in the  section in the web.config without needing to code C# except when accessing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saw your question, yes you are right, the answer I posted was related to web sites and therefore, it doesn't work with Web Applications or MVC

Here I will show you code to work with profiles in MVC using anonymous and authenticated user profiles

#### Output

**Anonymous user - No profile set yet**

[image]

**Anonymous user - profile set**

[image]

**Authenticated user - profile migrated**

[image]

#### Web.config

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
<profile inherits="ProfileInWebApplicationMVC1.UserProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

#### UserProfile class

```
public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
{
    public static UserProfile GetProfile()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Profile as UserProfile;
    }

    [SettingsAllowAnonymous(true)]
    public DateTime? LastVisit
    {
        get { return base["LastVisit"] as DateTime?; }
        set { base["LastVisit"] = value; }
    }

    public static UserProfile GetProfile(string userID)
    {
        return ProfileBase.Create(userID) as UserProfile;
    }
}
```

#### Home controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        var p = UserProfile.GetProfile();

        return View(p.LastVisit);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveProfile()
    {
        var p = UserProfile.GetProfile();

        p.LastVisit = DateTime.Now;
        p.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

#### Index view

```
@if (!this.Model.HasValue)
{
    @: No profile detected
}
else
{
    @this.Model.Value.ToString()
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProfile", "Home"))
{
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Save profile" />
}
```

And finally, when you are an anonymous user **you can have your own profile** however, once you register to the site, you need to *migrate* your current profile to be used with your new account. This is because ASP.Net membership, creates a new profile when a user logs-in

#### Global.asax, code to migrate profiles

```
    public void Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous(object sender, ProfileMigrateEventArgs args)
    {
        var anonymousProfile = UserProfile.GetProfile(args.AnonymousID);
        var f = UserProfile.GetProfile(); // current logged in user profile

        if (anonymousProfile.LastVisit.HasValue)
        {
            f.LastVisit = anonymousProfile.LastVisit;
            f.Save();
        }

        ProfileManager.DeleteProfile(args.AnonymousID);
        AnonymousIdentificationModule.ClearAnonymousIdentifier();
        Membership.DeleteUser(args.AnonymousID, true);
    }
```

Comment: wow don't know what else to say except thank you again lol..cheers