# User profiles in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I have an asp.net project and I am trying to develop the user profile part, so that users can log in with their own profile (profile containing admin and users).

Is it okay to set a cookie on users computer, when the user is logged in and then let the user browse in site?
I mean after after I check user name and password, by checking this cookie on every page I let the user browse the page or redirect to the login page.

Is this way okay?
Is this safe to use?
Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: Check SqlMembershipProvider it will save you a lot of your time. It already supports what are you looking for. For more info visit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SqlProfileProvider. Adding profile properties can be done by adding some code to your web.confing (inside system.web section, database for sqlprofile structure must be present):

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDB" applicationName="MyApplication" description="SqlProfileProvider"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="LanguageId" allowAnonymous="false" type="System.Int32"/>
    <add name="Company" allowAnonymous="false" type="System.String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

In this example I have added two profile properties languageId nad Company.
You can access this properties using following code:

```
ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create("SomeUserName");
string company = (string)profile["Company"];
```

For additional info about SqlProfileProvider visit following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.sqlprofileprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have written a couple of how-to answers about creating profiles from scratch:

- For Web Sites (where the profile object is automatically generated for you based on Web.config settings).

  - [How to persist anon user selection (ex: theme selection)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706349/1268570)
- For Web Applications (like MVC, where you need to specify the class inheriting `ProfileBase`)

  - [accessing profile.newproperty in MVC web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11706950/1268570)